# How to iterate through an NSArray containing NSDictionaries?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsobject

I have an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` each of which has 4 key values.

I'm creating objects for each NSDictionary and assigning the keys accordingly.

How can I iterate through the array of dictionaries and set each key as an attribute for the object?

I created the array seen in the picture below with this code:

```
if (muscleArray == nil)
    {
        NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
        NSMutableArray *rootLevel = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        self.muscleArray = rootLevel;
    }

    NSMutableArray *arrayForSearching = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSDictionary *muscleDict in self.muscleArray)
        for (NSDictionary *excerciseDict in [muscleDict objectForKey:@"exercises"])
            [arrayForSearching addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [excerciseDict objectForKey:@"exerciseName"], @"exerciseName",
                                          [muscleDict objectForKey:@"muscleName"], @"muscleName",
                                          [muscleDict objectForKey:@"musclePicture"], @"musclePicture", nil]];
    self.exerciseArray = arrayForSearching;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ExerciseDescriptions"
                                                     ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *descriptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSMutableArray *exercises = self.exerciseArray;
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [exercises count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [[exercises objectAtIndex:i] mutableCopy];

        NSString *exerciseName = [dict valueForKey:@"exerciseName"];
        NSString *description = [descriptions valueForKey:exerciseName];
        [dict setValue:description forKey:@"exerciseDescription"];
        [exercises replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dict];
    }
```

The code to create one object would look like this:

```
PFObject *preloadedExercises = [[PFObject alloc] initWithClassName:@"preloadedExercises"];
[preloadedExercises setObject:exerciseName forKey:@"exerciseName"];
[preloadedExercises saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }
}];
```

The array of dictionaries looks like this: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a quick glance at the Parse SDK that you mentioned in the comments, I think what you are looking for is this:

```
NSMutableArray *exercisesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
PFObject *preloadedExercises;
id value;

// Iterate through your array of dictionaries    
for (NSDictionary *muscleDict in self.muscleArray) {
    // Create our object
    preloadedExercises = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"preloadedExercises"];

    // For each dictionary, iterate through its keys
    for (id key in muscleDict) {
        // Grab the value
        value = [muscleDict objectForKey:key];

        // And assign each attribute of the object to the corresponding values
        [preloadedExercises setObject:value forKey:key];  
    }

    // Finally, add this newly created object to your array
    [exercisesArray addObject: preloadedExercises];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do what I was looking for.  I"m trying to just iterate through each dictionary in my array, and create an object for each using the Parse `PFObject` like this:  `PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1337] forKey:@"score"];
[gameScore setObject:@"Sean Plott" forKey:@"playerName"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"cheatMode"];
[gameScore save];`  They're doc is here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects

Comment: Oh, actually, I hadn't encountered Parse before, and wasn't sure what `PFObject` was in your question's code. `PFObject` does what I was referring to when I mentioned Key-Value Coding. Let me update my answer to show how this should work.

Comment: I think we're on the right track now.  Actually, you can ignore all the code I posted and just look at the picture of the NSArray of NSDictionaries that I posted with the keys in it and given that its called Array `exercises`.  I just need to iterate through that, I shouldn't have posted the code that I'm using to create that array because its unecessary.

Comment: Actually the code you posted may be correct, I just need to replace `muscleArray` with `exercises`

Answer (score 3):

```
// Assuming you want to do something with all of these objects you're creating
// We'll start by creating an NSMutableArray
NSMutableArray *newObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arrayOfDictionaries.count];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in arrayOfDictionaries)
{
    PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"preloadedExercises"];
    object.exerciseDescription = [dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseDescription"];
    object.exerciseName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"exerciseName"];
    object.muscleName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"muscleName"];
    object.musclePicture = [dictionary objectForKey:@"musclePicture"];

    // Add object to mutable array
    [newObjects addObject:object];
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this will do what I was looking for.  I"m trying to just iterate through each dictionary in my array, and create an object for each using the Parse `PFObject` like this:  `PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1337] forKey:@"score"];
[gameScore setObject:@"Sean Plott" forKey:@"playerName"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"cheatMode"];
[gameScore save];`  They're doc is here: https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects

Comment: I've updated my answer to explicitly show the creation of the `PFObject` instance. Once this is done, `newObjects` will contain a PFObject for each dictionary in the original array. Then you can iterate through these and send `-saveInBackground:` if need be.

Comment: Hi Mark, can't I just add the `saveInBackground` code to the first `for loop` you have?

Comment: Ah yes. I thought parse provided a method for saving a collection of objects but I was wrong. I also see that there is a limit on how big each request can be so yes, you should save at the end of each loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(NSDictionary* dictionary in yourArray){
// here you can iterate through. and assign every dictionary as you wish to.
}
```